# date arduino to firebase with sim800l

Tags: firebase, arduino

Mi objetivo es enviar datos a firebase desde arduino utilizando sim800l azul 5v en determinadas horas.
Utilizando las librerias TinyGsmClient y ArduinoHttpClient me funciona correctamente la conexion y envio de datos. Tambien obtener fecha con "AT+CCLK?" y formatearla pero no ambas a la vez.
El problema surge al obtener la fecha , despues de utilizar ese comando el modulo se conecta(parpadeo rapido) pero la conexion gprs me da error con lo que no puedo enviar datos. puede ser necesario otro codigo AT para permitir la conexion gprs?
Alguna sugerencia?? otra manera para obtener la fecha?

Comment: Una pregunta sin un ejemplo mínimo verificable del código implementado y los errores y salidas incorrectas, es una pregunta incompleta. Edita tu pregunta y complétala

Comment: Entiendo que la pregunta debería ser mas concreta...  sin embargo con el camino que llevo con  Arduino y modulos sim pienso que hay tantas posibilidades de error aparte de código que lo he preguntado de manera abstracta por si alguien le ha pasado... Gracias y un saludo